# Laravel post directly to resource index

Tags: php, laravel, controller, resources, request

I have one, hopefully small, issue. I need to be able to post directly to my index. Right now I am using a resource controller:

```
Route::resource('appointments', 'AppointmentsController');
```

And I want to be able to update my index view from my resource controller using dropdowns to post values to my index. So I can use those values like so:

```
public function index(Request $request)
```

Up untill this point I was using a different route to post to, and then redirect to my appointments.index route, and so on. But that is silly. I want to still be able to use my resource controller, otherwise I need to create lots of routes (since I am using a bunch of resource controllers and I need to be able to post directly to the index on all of them).

What is the most efficient way to resolve this? I did try to open my form using an url and then add a trailing slash at the end, but that did not do the trick.

Comment: you need to use now route get or post in this same controller,if you want to use route resource with non restful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's quite simple, just create your Resource controller without the store route, like this:

```
Route::resource('appointments', 'AppointmentsController', ['except' => ['store']]);
```

Then add your route before the resource declaration, something like this:

```
Route::post('appointments', 'AppointmentsController@index');
Route::resource('appointments', 'AppointmentsController', ['except' => ['store']]);
```

Comment: True, that would work, but that means I cannot use the store route anymore, which I am using as well. Or I should simply create a seperate route for storing (creating) new appointments.

Comment: Well you can't use both, because the store route also posts to the url  `appointments`

Comment: So I just have to see what works best for me, thanks! :)